# how to get data from wordpress application using WP API

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I am working on a Ionic application. I need data from a wordpress website already developed. I have no idea of wordpress. I installed WP-API Rest. So basically it is a e-commerce application which have Categories and Subcategories and for each categories it have some products. I tried for hours to get the data.
Please if any one could help....
Let me know if any information needed.

Comment: If the website use WooCommerce, you first need to authenticate : http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-https

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the solution but now getting the following error {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}